# South migration for custom AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration, django-south

I just switched over to using a custom AUTH_USER_MODEL following [this post](https://hurricanelabs.com/blog/django-user-models/).

It suggested the following forward migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    db.rename_table('auth_user', 'myapp_myuser')
    db.rename_table('auth_user_groups', 'myapp_myuser_groups')
    db.rename_table('auth_user_user_permissions',
    'myapp_myuser_user_permissions')
    if not db.dry_run:
        # For permissions to work properly after migrating
        orm['contenttypes.contenttype'].objects.filter(app_label='auth',
            model='user').update(app_label='myapp', model='myuser')
```

This works great for **existing** databases for which `syncdb` was executed while `AUTH_USER_MODEL` was still the default `auth.User` in *settings.py*. This is because the `auth_user` table would've been created.

However, in a **new** installation using the new *settings.py* containing `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`, running `syncdb` does NOT create the `auth_user` table. Of course, if I now go and run the migrations for myapp using `manage.py migrate myapp`, it gives the following error:

```
Running migrations for myapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_custom_auth_user_model.
 > myapp:0001_initial
 > myapp:0002_custom_auth_user_model
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: RENAME TABLE `auth_user` TO `myapp_myuser`;
The error was: (1017, "Can't find file: '.\\mydb\\auth_user.frm' (errno: 2)")
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = RENAME TABLE `myapp_myuser` TO `auth_user`; []
   = RENAME TABLE `myapp_myuser_groups` TO `auth_user_groups`; []
   = RENAME TABLE `myapp_myuser_user_permissions` TO `auth_user_user_permissions`; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: myapp:0002_custom_auth_user_model
DatabaseError: (1017, "Can't find file: '.\\mydb\\auth_user.frm' (errno: 2)")
```

I thought of wrapping the migration in a conditional to check if the `auth_user` table already exists, but South does not seem to support getting the database tables and I'm not sure this is the best idea either.

How can I fix the migration so it'll work with both new and existing installations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming auth\_user breaks migrations on fresh setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928273/renaming-auth-user-breaks-migrations-on-fresh-setup)